# Java synchronized block and the visibility guarantees for an explicit lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class, in which I have a state that consists of several fields-collections.

Now, I have methods that change that state. And there are methods that are reading it.

I want to use an explicit lock to guard state change modifications.

```
class Sample {
  private final Map<String> a = new HashMap<>();
  private final Map<String> b = new HashMap<>();
  private final Map<String> c = new HashMap<>();

  // protects the state of variables a,b,c so that the state modifications are atomic
  private final Object lock = new Object();

  ...
  // other fields

  private void changeState(StateChange obj){
     synchronized(lock){
         changeA();
         changeB();
         changeC();
    }
  }

  private State readState(){
     synchronized(lock){
         return buildStateFromABC();
    }
  }

}
```

If this class is accessed/modified in a multi-threaded environment, will each thread see up-to-date contents of fields a,b,c after entering a guarded area?

There is no direct correlation between the lock and those fields, or is there something?

I know that I can use an intrinsic lock here and just slap synchronized on methods, but I want to minimize the protected area.

What would be the preferred way of synchronizing here? On explicit lock object or on `this`?

Comment: There is a direct correlation -- it's the same lock in both cases.  That guarantees visibility.  If there's something specific you're asking about please point it out.  On my read through I didn't see anything amiss.

Comment: I'm sure we have a ton of answers on this already.  If none work for you, please point out where you think your question is different.  Here's just one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653230/in-a-java-synchronized-block-are-writes-visible-on-all-fields-or-just-the-synch

Comment: (You can restrict your search to a specific site in Google like this: "java synchronization visibility site:stackoverflow.com")

Comment: The only thing I see that’s a problem with this code is that the scope of the lock is at class level but the things protected are scoped at instance level. So if you have two instances of this class they’ll both be using the same lock, which could be an unnecessary performance hit. But visibility wise the question linked to by @markspace should answer this.

Comment: Right the `static` use of a lock could cause multiple threads to be blocked when they might not need to be.  There's less concurrency here than there could be.  But if any method in above accesses a static variable then the static lock is likely required.

Comment: So, this happened-before guarantee will ensure that each thread will see up-to-date state of every field that comprises that internal state of a Sample object?

Comment: I do not need a static lock, just an oversight on my end.

Comment: Yes, *happens-before* in Java is what guarantees memory visibility.  It's basically the same thing as a memory barrier.  If you want the full skinny, Brian Goetz's book *Java Concurrency in Practice* is the best for explaining how it all works.

Comment: I read that book ages ago, need a refresher,  thanks!

Comment: @markspace do not mesh together barriers and guarantees from the JLS. It might simplify sometimes reasoning, but in the long run it will bring more pain than usage.

Comment: I may not understand memory barriers well.  I'd appreciate a source that explains how they work, if you happen to have one. @Eugene

Comment: @markspace the ones I really cherish, are mostly in Russian (at least the good ones), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK-7GCCDF_I) is one in English that is very good too.

Comment: @markspace the ones I really cherish, are mostly in Russian (at least the good ones), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK-7GCCDF_I) is one in English that is very good too.

Comment: Thanks, I've got a huge backlog of "watch later" videos on YouTube, I'll try to get to that soon.  It describes memory barriers, yes?  I feel I already know the Java memory model quite well.  @Eugene

Comment: @markspace as said in the video title, it is an "unlearning" the JMM, which _very_ few people should learn to begin with. So deferring to the JMM/barriers, when coding in java, is a path of no return, imho.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll check it out. @Eugene

Comment: If you do not want the lock to prevent your class from being serializable, you can also use
 `private final Object lock = new Object[0];`
 Whether serialization is a good thing, is another discussion.
(https://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, there is the `JLS`, [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> An unlock on a monitor **happens-before** every subsequent lock on **that** monitor.

So your methods `readState` and `changeState` (because they use the *same* lock), will create that *happens-before* edge, needed for proper visibility.

There is also this part in the `JLS` that says:

> If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent (§17.4.3).

Followed by :

> This is an extremely strong guarantee for programmers. Programmers do not need to reason about reorderings to determine that their code contains data races. Therefore they do not need to reason about reorderings when determining whether their code is correctly synchronized. Once the determination that the code is correctly synchronized is made, the programmer does not need to worry that reorderings will affect his or her code.

So if you understand how the happens before connections happens (according to the JLS guarantees), your code is thread safe.

---

As to which to favor, a `synchronized` method or an explicit lock (I would still suggest a `ReentrantLock` in your case), may be [this read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034473/when-young-gc-occurs-ext-root-scanning-takes-a-long-time-what-is-the-possible/65135033#65135033) can help a bit.